# Simple Asynchronous function call in Neovim (defer_fn or timer_start ?)

Tags: neovim, async

I'm trying to create a very simple shortcut that saves the buffer and cleans the writing message after a second.

```
nmap <silent> <leader>w :w<CR>:sleep 1<CR>:echo ""<CR>
```

This works fine but I would like to make the message cleaning asynchronous (so I don't get stuck for 1 second). Looking into asynchronous solutions, it is not clear if the way to achieve that would be via timer_start, defer_fn, or something else.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! FWIW, I don't often feel a need to clear the message :) besides, any time I use `:`, `/`, or `?` it goes away. Also `:redraw` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with [`:h timer_start()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/eval.html#timer_start%28%29). Create a function which will write the buffer, create a function which clears the message and create a timer to call this function. Then map `<leader>w` to call this function:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>w :call SaveAndClear()<CR>

function! SaveAndClear()
    write
    function! ClearMessage(timer)
        echo ""
    endfunction
    call timer_start(1000, 'ClearMessage')
endfunction
```

The syntax could be simplified with a lambda (I copied the syntax of an example in [`:h closure`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/eval.html#closure)):

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>w :w<CR>:call timer_start(1000, {-> execute("echo ''", "")})<CR>
```

Also, always create non-recursive mappings `nnoremap` unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks a lot @statox!

Comment: @MarcoNetto Glad it works and welcome to our site :) If this answers your question as you expected you  can mark it as accepted to help future readers find this answer too, [you can have a look at the help center about accepting and voting for an answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Why echoing something at all, when a redraw just does it? Also I usually just hit `Ctrl-L` to get rid of that write status message, no need to do it automatically and then possibly just miss it, because you are distracted for that 1 second :/

Comment: I do agree that I don't see the point of deleting the status automatically I would never use that on my own config but if OP think they need it... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ And yes there are better ways of suppressing the message but I think what's important here is the call of a timer from a mapping, once they know how to do it OP can change the actual action for whatever they want.